# Set property with this keyword, javascript

Tags: javascript

How do I set a property in an object which points to an array in the same object?

The "this" keyword seems natural but i get an error.

This is my object. http://jsbin.com/IPuFEpa/1/edit?js,console,output . It is the property "activeFlowUnit" that is not working.

```
var Converter = {
  flow: {
    valueInSiUnit: 55,
    valueInUserUnit: 0.75
  },
  units: {
    flowUnits: [{
      title: 'm3/s',
      fullTitle: 'cubic meter / second',
      decimals: 5,
      factor: 1
    }, {
      title: 'l/s',
      fullTitle: 'liter / second',
      decimals: 3,
      factor: 1000
    }]
  },
  activeFlowUnit: this.units.flowUnits[0], //Not working
  greet: function(){
    return this.units.flowUnits[0]; //Works
  },
  convertUnit: function(valueInSIUnit, factor, decimalFactor){
    var decimalConvert = Math.pow(10, decimalFactor);
    return  Math.round((valueInSIUnit * factor)*decimalConvert)/decimalConvert;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a function to create the right scope, as that's what functions do

```
activeFlowUnit: function() {
    return this.units.flowUnits[0];
},
```

then you would of course have to call it like a function as well

Answer (score 2):

You just need to be aware of this :

```
var o = {
    prop: this === o, // false
    meth: function () {
        this === o; // true
    }
};
this === o; // false
```

Comment: @downvoter Well, I just tried to hit the core problem while avoiding a long speech.

Comment: Cool :) I agree this is not a chef-d'oeuvre but it seems to me that the OP has enough skills to figure out the meaning of this code. Thanks @Eric :)

Answer (score 1):

I would give the Object.defineProperty a try to have a property with a getter and a setter :

```
Object.defineProperty(Converter, "activeFlowUnit", {
    get: function activeFlowUnit() {
        if (!this.units.active)
            this.units.active = this.units.flowUnits[0];
        return this.units.active;
    },
    set: function activeFlowUnit(val) {
        this.units.active = val;
    }
});

console.log(Converter.activeFlowUnit);
Converter.activeFlowUnit = Converter.units.flowUnits[1];
console.log(Converter.activeFlowUnit);
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/IPuFEpa/8/edit)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it within the object initializer itself, there's no way to refer to the object that's being constructed by the initializer from the property initializers, because the object doesn't exist yet.

You can do it afterward, though:

```
var Converter = {
    // ...all of your other init
};
Converter.activeFlowUnit = Converter.units.flowUnits[0];
```

The reason `this` works within functions you use as property initializers is twofold:

1. The function doesn't get called until later, after the object has been created
2. Calling the function via the object reference (`Converter.convertUnit`) is what sets `this`.

Answer (score 0):

`this` only points to the current object when a method is invoked. You can just assign the member of object to a temporary variable in the literal:

```
var units;
var Converter = {
  ...
  units: units = {
    flowUnits: [...]
  },
  activeFlowUnit: units.flowUnits[0], //Works
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite common [pattern](https://github.com/shichuan/javascript-patterns/blob/master/function-patterns/immediate-object-initialization.html) with object init like that is to have init method.

```
 var Converter = {
   flow: {
      valueInSiUnit: 55,
      valueInUserUnit: 0.75
   },
   ...
   init : function() {
       this.activeFlowUnit = this.units.flowUnits[0]
   }
 }

 Converter.init()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite the whole thing creating a prototype for the converter object (that does all the required initializations) and then instantiating object(s) from that.

This way:

```
// First create a prototype of your converter...

// ...this is the constructor

function Converter(params) {
    this.flow  = params.flow;
    this.units = params.units;
    this.activeFlowUnit = this.units.flowUnits[0];
}

// ...these are the methods

Converter.prototype.greet = function() {
    return this.units.flowUnits[0];
};

Converter.prototype.convertUnit = function(valueInSIUnit, factor, decimalFactor) {
    var decimalConvert = Math.pow(10, decimalFactor);
    return  Math.round((valueInSIUnit * factor)*decimalConvert)/decimalConvert;
};



// Then instantiate an object passing the parameters

var converter = new Converter( {
    flow: {
        valueInSiUnit: 55,
        valueInUserUnit: 0.75
    },
    units: {
        flowUnits: [{
            title: 'm3/s',
            fullTitle: 'cubic meter / second',
            decimals: 5,
            factor: 1
        }, {
            title: 'l/s',
            fullTitle: 'liter / second',
            decimals: 3,
            factor: 1000
        }]
    } 
} );
```

Now

```
this.activeFlowUnit = this.units.flowUnits[0];
```

has a scope as **this** points to the new intatiated object.